Jetpack compose "Unresolved Reference" errors suddenly appeared in project errors
My app was working just fine. Then I made a new file (that has nothing to do with the file that has the errors) and an "assets" folder. Suddenly, when I tried to build it, it shows unresolved reference errors in project errors tab, while there's no error in file errors tab. All the errors are about my custom font and colors (jakartaSansFontFamily and LightTeal). I put my custom fonts in "ui/theme/Type.kt" and "ui/theme/Color.kt" for my custom colors.
I use those custom color and font everywhere in the app, but it only shows errors only on this particular file.
This is my code
@Composable
fun HaditsInfoCard(hadits: Hadits) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 5.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = LightTeal)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = hadits.haditsNumber,
                fontFamily = jakartaSansFontFamily,
                color = Color.Black
            )
            Text(
                text = hadits.matan,
                fontFamily = jakartaSansFontFamily,
                color = Color.Black
            )
            Text(
                text = hadits.translate,
                fontFamily = jakartaSansFontFamily,
                color = Color.Black
            )
            Text(
                text = hadits.rawi,
                fontFamily = jakartaSansFontFamily,
                color = Color.Black
            )
        }
    }
}

I tried retyping the code, deleting the new file and "assets" folder I created, but it didn't do anything.

Roll back to the last working version and make a diff. If you don't use a version control system like Git, this may just be the time to get started with it. Perhaps your IDE also stored a local history that is still available for you to make the diff.

@Leviathan I'm using android studio. I haven't used the version control yet because I'm making apps just to do my college assignments for now, local history option seems unavailable to me because of that

@Leviathan I'm using Git now and managed to find a way to access local history (it was greyed out) and reverted my project, but the errors are still there.

You can create a new project and then copy the files from the old project over, step by step, to see when it fails.
